# Allow client to retrieve users from keycloak

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, keycloak-rest-api

I want to let my client application access user information from keycloak. Therefore, I created another realm (myrealm1) in keycloak and within that realm I created a new client (myclient1).

## keycloak configuration:

### Client configuration

[image: Client myclient1 configuration]

Actually, I tried a lot of other combinations without success.

In the client scopes tab, I added the admin client scope
In the service account roles tab, I added the admin role

### Client scope configuration

For the admin client scope, I assigned the admin role in the scope tab.

### Realm role configuration

For the admin realm role, I assigned the admin role in the associated role tab.

## REST API Calls

These are the REST API calls I am using

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=myclient1' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=PehR9f95woZmEEHcKfSgPaosu1Yt6P9s' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

Returns

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJS...",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "refresh_expires_in": 0,
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "not-before-policy": 0,
    "scope": "email profile admin"
}
```

So far so good, I do get a token.

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/myrealm/users' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJS...'
```

Returns
HTTP 403

```
{
    "error": "unknown_error"
}
```

This is not as expected. The expected result would be the user information.

Btw, I do get it working for the admin user of the master realm

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=admin-cli' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=password' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password'
```

But this is not what I want. I would like to get it working for my custom client.

## Setup

I am using keycloak 19.0.3

## My question

What is missing to get it working? I. e. How do I enable my client to make use of the keycloak REST APIs such as /admin/realms/myrealm/users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to:

- your realm;
- your Client;
- then go to service account;

[image]

- Click on Assign Role;
- Select Filter by clients;
- and search for 'realm-management'

[image]

- Select and assign the desired roles.